# Interactive data table with crossfilter groups

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

So i have a pretty big dataset of dates and id's, and I am trying to create statistics module of sorts.

Sample data :

```
{"ID":92941,"ACCOMPLISH_DATE":"2015-08-07 13:50:28","RECEIVER_ID":8840,"SENDER_ID":5865,"STATUS_ID":7,"SCENARIO_ID":2,"CREATE_DATE":"2015-08-07 11:41:16"}
{"ID":92942,"ACCOMPLISH_DATE":"2015-08-07 13:50:28","RECEIVER_ID":8841,"SENDER_ID":5865,"STATUS_ID":5,"SCENARIO_ID":3,"CREATE_DATE":"2015-08-07 12:41:16"}
```

While I succeeded of making interactive charts, I am also trying to make a simple table to display how many of each `STATUS_ID`'s each `RECEIVER_ID` has in the selected time frame. While the chart updates, and changes dates dynamically, I couldn't manage to make it show the data I need.

I was searching a lot and didn't find anything relating this issue. Only thing I found was that I can't give data table same groups as other charts, sadly I weren't able to find a good example as how I should change my code.
Another solution I found was to use other libraries, which would be good if I had only this single table to display, but since multiple charts are needed this is not a good solution.

My code for groups:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var AccDateDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.ACCOMPLISH_DATE});
var statusDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.RECEIVER_ID;});
var countPerStatus = statusDim.group().reduceCount();
```

And code for creating actual table:

```
var datatable   = dc.dataTable("#dc-data-table");
    datatable
        .dimension(statusDim)
         .group(function (d) {
        var format = d3.format('02d');
        return d.ACCOMPLISH_DATE.getFullYear() + '/' + format((d.ACCOMPLISH_DATE.getMonth() + 1));
    })
        .columns([
            function(d) {return d.STATUS_ID;}
        ]);
```

It would be very useful if someone could provide me with an example, how it should be done, or at least explain how it can/why it can't be done. I am open to suggestions, since this table has been confusing me to no end.

Also might be useful: Current output of my table

```
2016/05
7
7
7
2016/04
7
5
7
```

Comment: You can actually use a group for the dimension - see [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/table-on-aggregated-data.html) ([source](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/examples/table-on-aggregated-data.html))

Comment: @Gordon I found this example earlier, but was put off because every time I was passing my group countPerStatus I got this error in console: `TypeError: _chart.dimension(...).bottom is not a function`. I have since found that it was caused by weird default settings of .order(). Now as I pass that group it works, but I get `d.ACCOMPLISH_DATE is undefined` which I believe is caused by incorrect definition of my group. As I still don't have full understanding of reduce functions I am quite confused how to properly define the group so it would properly return count and wouldn't lose date.

Comment: I think it's not a simple question because it's not a simple problem. I take it you are looking for a table of the count per status per receiver per date? That's a bit of a complex reduction.

Comment: Actually I'm not even sure how to display that, given it is three-dimensional.

Comment: [Here is my start on a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/n417fb64/7/), in case I don't return to this.

Comment: This table should be more like a tree, crossfilter gets selected date and possibly receiver(if selected), and then displays status id count for that selection. An example: Date: `2015/03 -> Receiver_ID: 8840 -> Status count: 7:1, 8:3, 9:20` I'll try to find a solution for another day or so, and if I wont, I'll probably resort to roundabout way by making the table with data got from a custom SQL query generated with data from crossfilter selection.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I have seen some tree UIs connected to dc.js but none are formally supported. If you can use a graphical representation, the [sunburst chart](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/907) is furthest along. Folks have also posted code for a [treemap](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/129). Don't know why I haven't seen code for a simple collapsible text tree.